# How to read out data from sql-database when several criteria match

Tags: mysql, database

I have a normalized sql-database with several tables and an html-form to read out the data. There is one table that contains product-characteristics and any product can have one or more characteristics.

Main table: product_main pm,
Table with characteristics: product_characteristics pc, 
product_id is the foreign key.

```
id | product_id | product_name | characteristic
1  | 27         | Product_C    | characteristic5 
2  | 27         | Product_C    | characteristic11
3  | 27         | Product_C    | characteristic3 
4  | 27         | Product_C    | characteristic47 
5  | 27         | Product_C    | characteristic34 
6  | 28         | Product_D    | characteristic29 
7  | 28         | Product_D    | characteristic63 
8  | 28         | Product_D    | characteristic2
```

Now, I want to read out all product_names that match the selected criteria. This works fine, when only one characteristic is selected:

```
SELECT pm.name 
FROM product_main pm, product_characteristics pc 
WHERE pc.characteristic = 'characteristic47' 
  AND pm.id = pc.product_id
```

The correct result is: Product_C.

If more than one characteristics are selected simultaneously, e.g.:

```
SELECT pm.name 
FROM product_main pm, product_characteristics pc 
WHERE pc.characteristic = 'characteristic47' 
  AND pc.characteristic = 'characteristic11' 
  AND pm.id = pc.product_id
```

there is no result, although Product_C matches both criteria.
Could someone please tell me, how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One option uses conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT product_id, product_name
FROM product_main
GROUP BY product_id, product_name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN characteristic = 'characteristic47' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN characteristic = 'characteristic11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

If you also want to retain all original records in `product_main` which have both matching characteristics, then you can join the above table back to your original table:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM product_main t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT product_id
    FROM product_main
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN characteristic = 'characteristic47' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
           SUM(CASE WHEN characteristic = 'characteristic11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
) t2
    ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `pc.characteristic` cannot be both `characteristic47` AND `characteristic11` at the same time, but it could be (`characteristic47` OR `characteristic11`)

So amend the query like so

```
SELECT pm.name 
FROM product_main pm, product_characteristics pc 
WHERE ( pc.characteristic = 'characteristic47' OR
        pc.characteristic = 'characteristic11' )
  AND pm.id = pc.product_id
```

You sould also be using JOIN's like so

```
SELECT pm.name 
FROM product_main pm
JOIN product_characteristics pc ON  pm.id = pc.product_id
WHERE ( pc.characteristic = 'characteristic47' OR
        pc.characteristic = 'characteristic11' )
```